# How can I append a different element for each list in a column in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, if-statement, apply

I have a dataframe, df, with lists in a specific column, col_a. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col_a'] = [[1,2,3], [3,4], [5,6,7]]
```

I want to use conditions on these lists and apply specific modifications, including appends. For example, imagine that if the length of the list is > 2, I want to append another element, which is the sum of the last two elements of the current list. So, considering the first list above, I have [1, 2, 3] and I want to have [1, 2, 3, 5].

What I tried to do was:

```
df.loc[:, col_a] = df[col_a].apply(
                    lambda value: value.append(value[-2]+value[-1]) 
                          if len(value) > 1 else value)
```

But the result in that column is `None` for all the elements of the column.

Can someone help me, please?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a [mcve] to get better responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `append` is an in place function and returns `None`. You need to add two lists together. So a working example with dummy variable would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cola':[[1,2],[2,3,4]], 'dum':[1,2]})
df['cola']=df.cola.apply(lambda x: (x+[sum(x[-2:])] if len(x)>2 else x))
```

Comment: I believe she wants to append the last two elements, not their sum: `x+ x[-2:]`

Comment: @Andrea I believe this part of the question clearly asks for appending the sum "I want to append another element, which is the sum of the last two elements"

Comment: My mistake, you are perfectly correct, I didn't see Fibonacci coming XD

Comment: Thank you, it works! I just don't understand why the dummy variable is needed. I tried to use only the second line of code at it works alone. Could you explain that idea, please?

Comment: @sofiacosta29 It's not needed, just extra columns in the dataframe to make sure rest of the DF is fine. If this works, please consider accepting it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use append try this:

```
def my_logic_for_list(values):
    if len(values) > 2:
        return values + [values[-2]+values[-1]]
    return values
df['new_a'] = df['a'].apply(my_logic_for_list)
```

You can not use append inside lambda function.

Comment: lists will be passed to functions by reference, not values. So this solution changes the dataFrame while the function is running and then overwrites it again which is unnecessary operation.